# how to fire an event when h:inputText is focused out in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am programming a Web-Application with Java EE and JSF.

I want to fire a function in javascript when h:inputText is focussed out. I tried something, but it does not work.
What I did;

html;

```
<h:inputText id="devLati"
    class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-state-default ui-corner-all devInp"
    onmouseover="$(this).addClass('ui-state-hover')"
    onmouseout="$(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover')"
    onmousedown="$(this).addClass('ui-state-focus')"
    onmouseup="$(this).removeClass('ui-state-focus')"
    value="#{deviceRegionFacade.devLati}" />
```

js;

```
function initialize() {

...

$('#mainForm\\:devLati').focusout(function() {
    var newLat = $('#mainForm\\:devLati').val();
    var oldLat = marker.getPosition().lat();
    if(newLat != oldLat){
        removeMarker();
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, marker.getPosition().lng());
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: myLatLng,
            icon : 'resources/images/maintenanceAndLifeTimePage/unknown.png'
        });
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }

  });
}
```

- initialize() is called while opening the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

> <h:inputText id="devLati"
>         class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-state-default ui-corner-all devInp"
>         onfocus="$(this).addClass('ui-state-focus')"
>         onblur="$(this).removeClass('ui-state-focus')"
>     value="#{deviceRegionFacade.devLati}"
>     />

Comment: I use onblur feature on html tag and I put the function that contains operations what I want to make. It works :) I do not know why but when I try to fire an event via javascipt, it does not fire. Anyway, I use the solution via html that you offer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `blur` event:

```
$('#devLati').on('blur', function() {
    // Event handling code
});
```

> The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: @séan35 Can you create `jsfiddle`

Comment: thank u very much. But I reach the solution by using Ruslan's recommendation.